# Lag with first use of UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working on a simple universal ios app that displays images in a table, when the user selects an image it goes to a detail view which includes a larger view of the image and a UIButton/IBAction to save the image to their photo album..  I use the following code which for the most part works great, except the very first time the user presses "save" it hangs with a loooooong lag, a good 5-6sec.  If the user hits it multiple times during the lag time then the image gets saved multiple times, even if I include code to disable the button for a few seconds. The highlighted button also will not show during the first touch of the button. Thereafter it works fine.  Does anyone know the reason for the lag and how to fix it.  Thanks!

```
-(IBAction)saveBtn:(UIButton *)pressed{

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image.myimage, self, @selector(imageSavedToPhotosAlbum: didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil);

}

- (void)imageSavedToPhotosAlbum:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {  
    NSString *message;  
    NSString *title;  
    if (!error) {  
        title = NSLocalizedString(@"Image Saved", @"");  
        message = NSLocalizedString(@"You can now view the image in your photo album", @"");  
    } else {  
        title = NSLocalizedString(@"Save Failed", @"");  
        message = [error description];  
    }  
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title  
                                                    message:message  
                                                   delegate:nil  
                                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"")  
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];  
    [alert show];  
    [alert release];  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was unrelated to this code, and was instead due to memory usage with large image files in the table view.